# Derby DB Insert Error SQL state 21000

Tags: sql, database, derby, sql-insert

I am attempting to insert data into a table in my database. I am using an Oracle Apache Derby DB. I have the following code-

```
Insert into P2K_DBA.ODS_CNTRL
(ODS_LOAD_ID, ODS_STATUS, USR_WWID, USR_FIRST_NM, 
USR_LAST_NM, USR_DISPLAY_NM, USR_NT_ID,TOT_AMT, 
TOT_RCD_CNT, TOT_QTY, LAST_UPD_DT, ODS_ADJ_TYP, 
ODS_ADJ_DESC, APRV_WWID, APRV_FIRST_NM,APRV_LAST_NM, 
APRV_DISPLAY_NM, APRV_NT_ID, APRV_DT
)
values 
(6,'avail','64300339', 'Travis',
'Taylor', 'TT', '3339', 33,
15, 40, '7/10/2012', 'test',
'test', '64300337', 'Travis',
'Taylor', 'TT', '3339', '2/06/2013');
```

I ran this SQL command and received the following error-

"Error code -1, SQL state 21000: Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row.
Line 1, column 1"

I have ran this code successfully a few days ago. On top of that I have tried to manually enter in data in this table (using NetBeans) and have it auto generate the code, which resulted in the same error.

What is causing this error and how can I solve/bypass it?

Comment: The error message does not related to the posted SQL.

Comment: When I run that query that is the error message I received. I have tried to disconnect and reconnect the database to no avail. Am mentioned above, that code worked to add rows (data) to the table last week, but now I receive that error message.

Comment: I have fixed an aspect of this. I took away an existing trigger. Once the trigger was dropped the insert statement above worked fine. The trigger, returns multiple rows for a value, which was causing the error.

Comment: @eric_13 Learning of the day: so much for the nasty side effects of triggers

Answer (score 0):

One way in which you could run into this would be to do something like

CREATE FUNCTION F(...) ...

F((SELECT COL FROM T))

But you could instead write

... (SELECT F(COL) FROM T) provided the new context permits a subquery, that is.